Issue Integrating Twilio WhatsApp Webhook with AWS API Gateway
I'm trying to get user's WhatsApp response using Twilio sandbox environment and store the message in AWS S3 via AWS API Gateway & Lambda services but my configuration isn't correct showhow despite created a mapping template of application/x-www-form-urlencoded at Integration Request.
This is what I have typed in the Template body at Integration Request.
#set($httpPost = $input.path('$').split("&")
{
#foreach( $kvPair in $httpPost )
 #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
 #if( $kvTokenised.size() > 1 )
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : "$kvTokenised[1]"#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
 #else
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : ""#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
 #end
#end
}

In my API Gateway dashboard the API calls are always 5xx error. I have no idea what is wrong with my configuration, please help.

Does your Lambda function get called? Can you show the CloudTrail log by making a call?
